# Open X over clustered IIS

Tags: xml-rpc, openx

I am trying to have an openx setup with Windows Server 2008 r2 , php 5.4 and mySql in cluster of two IIS load balanced Web Servers.

I am trying to hit the api from an external c# code but when i try to login to get the session id i have as a result "Method is not Allowed" from the iis server.

The web interface for the openX online systems works perfect.

Did you do any special configuration at the iis server to accept xml rpc proxy connections for the included api?

Do you have any special idea??

Thanks for your time
George